# Php Auth header doesn't work

Tags: php, http-headers

After a long research on internet , I have found a method that seems to work , but not on the website I want.

```
<?php

$username = '';
$password = '';
$url = 'https://web.esme.fr/pscripts/bsp';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));

$data = file_get_contents($url , false, $context);

 echo($data);


?>
```

I have tried this on another part of the website and it works , but on the page I want $data contains nothing !!!!

I know that sometimes this url asks 2 times the authentication , sometimes not.

Any suggestion ?

Thank you

Comment: you dont use your $context anywhere? see http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php && http://php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: Just forgotten on my post, sorry, any other suggestion ?

Comment: is this code located above the header? if it is not there is your problem

Comment: this code is used to retrieve the content of the page : $url (  https://web.esme.fr/pscripts/bsp );  which requires an authentication !